# Android Firebase - Error in searchbar

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing a search bar in my android app with Firebase.
This is my database

[image]

and this is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){

        SearchManager manager = ( SearchManager ) getSystemService ( Context.SEARCH_SERVICE );
        SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                mDatabase.child ( "Blog" ).equalTo ( query );

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I need to research in "title", "desc" and "username" but I see that I did something wrong, because it doesn't work. What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The last paragraph of your question doesn't make a huge amount of sense. In fact you've provided very little detail altogether. Please clarify what you're trying to do and what's going wrong.

Comment: Can you explain your code please? It seems that there is not including any search functionality.

Comment: Solved at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966414/android-how-to-filter-the-recyclerview-of-firebase/45996866#45996866 , thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) { 

    mDatabase.child( "Blog" ).child("title").equalTo( query );
   return true; 
}
```